# Calling a function from an html document will not generate an alert

Tags: javascript, html

Hi all thanks for taking a look.

I am trying to call a javascript function when I click on the update button.

Here is the javascript

```
var text2Array = function() {
// takes the value from the text area and loads it to the array variable.

alert("test");

}
```

and the html

```
<button id="update" onclick="text2Array()">Update</button>
```

if you would like to see all the code check out this jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/runningman24/wAPNU/24/

I have tried to make the function global, no luck, I can get the alert to work from the html, but for some reason it won't call the function???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your fiddle, in the drop-down in the top left, change "onLoad" to "no wrap (head)"
Then change

```
var text2Array = function()
var pswdBld() = function()
```

to

```
function text2Array()
function pswdBld()
```

and it will alert as expected.

Answer (score 4):

You have an error in the declaration of the `pswdBld` function in your JavaScript.

```
...
var pswdBld() = function() {
        ---^^---
...
```

This is causing a syntax error and avoiding the load of your JavaScript file.

[See the corrected version.](http://jsfiddle.net/mC6v8/)

---

Also, you may consider binding the event and not inlining it.

```
<button id="update">Update</button>
```

```
var on = function(e, types, fn) {
  if (e.addEventListener) {
    e.addEventListener(types, fn, false);
  } else {
    e.attachEvent('on' + types, fn);
  }
};

on(document.getElementById("update"), "click", text2Array);​
```

[See it live.](http://jsfiddle.net/n9T3B/)

Answer (score 2):

You have a **syntax error** in the line below..

```
var pswdBld() = function
           ^---  Remove this
```

supposed to be

```
var pswdBld = function
```

Also make sure you are calling this script just at the **end of the body tag**..

Because you are using `Function Expressions` and not `Function Declaration`

```
var pwsdBld = function()    // Function Expression

function pwsdBld()         // Function Declaration
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/wAPNU/26/)**